# Jenkins on-demand build agents with SLURM

Tags: jenkins, hpc, slurm

I have access to an HPC cluster that uses SLURM to schedule jobs. I would like to evaluate having Jenkins submit jobs to the cluster.

As a simple test, it works to add the HPC login node to Jenkins, and configure a Jenkins job that executes `srun ... ./myprogram` on the login node. The `srun` command tells SLURM to assign a compute node and execute `./myprogram` on it.

This is not an ideal solution. Every Jenkins job has to be written to use `srun`. Scripts of more than one command are difficult. The compute node is not running the Jenkins agent so features are limited.

Can I have Jenkins instead spawn new nodes on-demand whenever a job is in the queue? It could then execute `srun ... jenkins-agent` on the login node to spawn a Jenkins agent on some compute node. And then the compute node would connect back to Jenkins and take the enqueued job. I would briefly a node `hpc-job-1643` appear and then it would disappear after the job completes.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can have Jenkins launch nodes on-demand through Slurm.

1. Create a new node. Set the remote root directory to something accessible from all nodes of your Slurm cluster.
2. Set a label that your jobs will use to bring up this node.
3. Set Usage to "Only build jobs with label expression matching this node".
4. Select the "Launch agents via SSH" launch method (you need a plugin for this, I think)
5. Set the host to the hostname of your Slurm control node.
6. Set up the credentials and host key verification strategy as appropriate.
7. Click the "Advanced ..." button for the SSH launch method.
8. Set the Prefix Start Agent Command to `srun --pty [options for whatever resources and constraints you need] sh -c '`. Note the single quote at the end.
9. Set the Suffix Start Agent Command to `'`. That's a single quote.
10. For Availability, select "Bring this agent online when in demand, and take offline when idle". You'll need to set an in-demand delay (I use 0) and an idle delay.

Comment: Interesting, thanks I'll try this. Do you just set the number of executors on this node something very high, then?  Too many and the UI becomes a little ridiculous

Comment: No! Set the number of executors commensurate with the number of jobs you want to run on that one Slurm node. One of these Jenkins nodes is identically one Slurm node. You'll want multiple Jenkins executors if you want to run jobs on more than one Slurm node.

Comment: I'm trying this out but I'm curious about `--pty`. SLURM seems to ignore it because parent is not a tty. Without it, the agent seems to try to communicate over stdout and fails with some unexpected stream byte error. I can go to lengths to run in under a PTY but then errors also (unexpected EOF).

Comment: Yes, slurm gives me a warning with the --pty option, and claims to be ignoring it. However, the Jenkins agent won't work without it. There's no need to actually persuade ssh to use a pty.